# vba access query error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting a 3075 run time error when I try to filter thru multiple fields. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
Dim i As Variant
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strDelim As String


If Nz(Me.txtFullName, "") <> "" Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "FullName Like '*" & Replace(Me.txtFullName, "'", "''") & "*' AND "
End If

If Nz(Me.txtCivil, "") <> "" Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "CivilService_Status Like '*" & Replace(Me.txtCivil, "'", "''") & "*' AND "
End If

If Nz(Me.txtOffice, "") <> "" Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "Office_Title Like '*" & Replace(Me.txtOffice, "'", "''") & "*' AND "
End If

'If Nz(Me.cboDegree, "") <> "" Then
    'strWhere = strWhere & "[UpdatedBy] = '" & Me.cboDegree.Value & "' AND "
'End If

For Each i In Me.lstPosition.ItemsSelected
    strWhere = strWhere & strDelim & "Bureau='" & Me.lstPosition.ItemData(i) & strDelim & "' AND "
Next i

If Nz(Me.txtStartdate, "") <> "" Then 'from ,to salary range Dates
   strWhere = strWhere & "AgencyStart_Date BETWEEN #" & Me.txtStartdate & "# AND #" & Me.txtTodate & "# 'AND"
End If

'If Nz(Me.txtStartdate, "") <> "" Then 'from ,to salary range Dates
   ' strWhere = strWhere & "Request_Date BETWEEN #" & Me.txtStartdate & "# AND #" & Me.txtTo & "# 'AND"
'End If


For Each i In Me.lstBureau.ItemsSelected 'listbox
'If Not IsNull(i) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & strDelim & "Bureau='" & Me.lstBureau.ItemData(i) & strDelim & "' AND "
Next i
'End If

If Nz(Me.txtdivision, "") <> "" Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "Division Like '*" & Replace(Me.txtdivision, "'", "''") & "*' AND "
End If


For Each i In Me.lstFund.ItemsSelected 'listbox
   'If Not IsNull(i) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & strDelim & "Fund='" & Me.lstFund.ItemData(i) &        

 1. List item

strDelim & "' AND "
    'End If
Next i
    If Nz(Me.txtSalaryfrom, "") <> "" Then 'from ,to salary range Dates
     strWhere = strWhere & "SumOfAnnualized_Salary BETWEEN #" &       Me.txtSalaryfrom   
    & "# AND #" & Me.txtSalaryto & "# 'AND"
    End If




    If strWhere <> "" Then
    strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 5) 'Remove the extra AND
    Report_Onboard_summary.Filter = strWhere
    Report_Onboard_summary.FilterOn = True
   DoCmd.OpenReport "Onboard_summary", acViewPreview, WhereCondition:=strWhere
   Else
    Report_Onboard_summary.Filter = ""
   Report_Onboard_summary.FilterOn = False
    End If



End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

```
CivilService_Title Like '*Scientist*' AND Bureau='Part Time' AND AgencyStart_Date BETWEEN #8/22/2010# AND #12/23/2017#  AND [Fund] = 'CTL' AND SumOfAnnualized_Salary BETWEEN' 65000' AND '100000 '
```

This pops up now. I was able to fix the syntax mistake but now when the report pops up, the fields are blank

Comment: @HansUp I added it

Comment: Right after removing the trailing AND, display the where as Debug.Print strWhere  and if you don't see the problem, then paste that string in the above with {}.  The Bureau looks suspect, as it tries to string B=this AND B=that,  when I would think that what was wanted would be B=this OR B=that.

Comment: Also StartDate has a trailing single quote that probably is not wanted.

Comment: @donPablo  I am new to vba , you want me to remove the and from the immediate window?

Comment: Dear @Tyrone, please explain what that `1. List item` means between the lines of your code.

Comment: @WolfgangKais it was a type. I was able to fix the issue.  One column had abbreviations while the other I was connecting to did not